# How do I delete the last printed line on Python?

Tags: python

I've seen answers for deleting single characters, but that would take up a lot of room and I'd like this to work in a decent number of lines. I wish to make the impression of a moving cursor. This is the problem:

```
sys.stdout.write ('virus_prevention.fix_virus.attempt_enter')
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
time.sleep(2)
print ('virus_prevention.fix.virus.|attempt_enter')
time.sleep(2)
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
print ('virus_prevention.fix.virus|.attempt_enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
print ('virus_prevention.fix.viru|s.attempt.enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
print ('virus_prevention.fix.vir|us.attempt.enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
print ('virus_prevention.fix.vi|rus.attempt.enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
print ('virus_prevention.fix.v|irus.attempt.enter')
time.sleep(0.1)
sys.stdout.write('\033[2K\033[1G')
print ('virus_prevention.fix.|virus.attempt.enter')
```

And this is the output:

```
virus_prevention.fix_virus.attempt_enter
[2K[1Gvirus_prevention.fix.virus.|attempt_enter
[2K[1Gvirus_prevention.fix.virus|.attempt_enter
[2K[1Gvirus_prevention.fix.viru|s.attempt.enter
[2K[1Gvirus_prevention.fix.vir|us.attempt.enter
[2K[1Gvirus_prevention.fix.vi|rus.attempt.enter
[2K[1Gvirus_prevention.fix.v|irus.attempt.enter
[2K[1Gvirus_prevention.fix.|virus.attempt.enter
```

Which is NOT what I'm looking for. All I ask for is what code do I replace the `sys.stdout.write` line with? As you can see if I choose to put `sys.stdout.write` rather than print it gets rid of the extra text at the beginning.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/curses.html  looks as if you need some more control over your console.

Comment: Do you have a solution for Python 3?